# Remove Extra Space at Bottom of HTML List Item

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to remove the extra space displayed at the bottom of an HTML List Item tag **without setting a fixed height on the list item?**  I.e. I would like the list item to wrap to its content.

The following code shows 3 images in a horizontal list but the height of each li tag is 4px more than the image.  I would like it to wrap around the image i.e. to have the same width and height.  The width is currently the same but I just can't get the height to match.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><img alt="img1" src="img1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img alt="img2" src="img2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img alt="img3" src="img3.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li 
{ 
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/23LcK/

The gap is nothing to do with the `li`s. It's the space reserved for descenders in letters like `g` and `p` (because the `img`s are `inline` elements).

You can remove it with any of these applied to `li img`:

- `display: block`: http://jsfiddle.net/23LcK/1/
- `vertical-align` with `top` or `bottom`:  http://jsfiddle.net/23LcK/2/

Answer (score 14):

Set line-height:0; on the LI

```
li {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle to prove that it works - http://jsfiddle.net/jm9Tj/

Comment: Thanks @Anupam, this does work but the vertical-align: bottom; offered by @Ivan seems to be more robust when my code gets more complicated.

Comment: The true correct answer.  This is the source of that mysterious "extra space" once margin and padding are accounted for.

Comment: `display: block` is more robust solution here.

Comment: played with the line-height and 1.7 worked in my case - thansk

Answer (score 3):

This should do it for you.

```
ul{margin-bottom:0}
```

Answer (score 2):

li is wrapped in ul, which by default has some padding. Therefore as @Michael said, you have to zero out the padding of the ul element.

To avoid these problems, always try to use [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

FYI: Browsers apply a default CSS on web pages. That's why you see h1 elements that big when there is no CSS in your site. Because browsers have a default CSS. And since browsers come from different companies, they have different default CSS. For example, a browser may use 10px of margin for paragraphs, while another browser user 12px. This means that you have always inconsistencies in your design. But a CSS reset is made of some general rules that removes these default CSS styles.

Comment: That is not the reason for the extra space. Look at [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584004/remove-extra-space-at-bottom-of-html-list-item/6584207#6584207) for **a** correct answer (there are other ways to do this).

Comment: Thanks for the reset.css suggestion @Saeed. Using this did reduce the space by one or two pixels but it did not completely get rid of it.  @Ivan's answer is the only one which has completely got rid of it all.

Answer (score 0):

```
li img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan , this works great.  However I've awarded @thirtydot the accepted answer as he gives a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a default margin or padding on the img element in the browser you are using. You can remove this using something like this:

```
li img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As different web browsers use different default styles it's recommended that you use a reset stylesheet. This sets a whole load of stuff to sensible defaults so you get more consistent styling across browsers. Because it resets everything to sensible defaults you should always load the reset stylesheet before any other stylesheets.

As @Saeed mentioned there is a good reset stylesheet as well as more information on why you should use them [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).