# CSS spacing/padding issue with image elements

Tags: css

Am migrating a website to a new hosting site (Squarespace). Mostly easy, good, and painless...except for 1 issue related to display of features that have the following elements: header image, background image, and another image layered over the background. In all cases of this, there's a gap between the header image and background - maybe 4-5 pixels. I've attached an image showing the issue. Happens across browsers I can test (Firefox, IE, Chrome).

This doesn't seem to happen if I add text first (before the image)....and it doesn't happen in the original website - only when I migrate it to Squarespace. I can only make the extra spaces go away if I adjust the line height to something ridiculous which scrunches the text.  I've checked to see if some other Squarespace CSS (like overall "body" settings or something) might be effecting this - nothing I can see.

Would love any advice. Thanks!

Here's the CSS (no changes in it from original site to new platform):

```
    #hpLeftBuckets {float:left;width:544px;}

    #hpGetInspired {width:510px;float:left;padding-left:34px;}
    #hpGetInspiredMain {width:470px;height:292px;float:left;background:url('/storage/images/hp_gisp_bg.jpg');background-repeat:repeat-y;}

    #hpGISYPWrapper {width:510px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:34px;float:left;padding-left:20px;}
    #hpGISYPWrapper ul {margin-left: 0px;margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:6px;margin-right:50px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left: 0px;list-style: none;}
    #hpGISYPWrapper ul li{padding-left: 18px;padding-bottom:8px;background-image: url(/storage/images/greenLeafBullet.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 0px 2px;}

    .hp_GISYP-BG {background:url('/storage/images/hp_GISYP-BG.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;width:245px;height:222px;background-position: top;}
    .hp_GISYP-Img {padding-left:17px;border:none;text-align:left;}
    .hp_GISYP-Text {text-align:left;padding:10px 17px 8px 17px;}
    .hp_GISYP-small {padding-top:3px;}
    .hp_GISYP-small a {font-size:9px;}
    #hpGetInvolved {width:245px;float:left;padding-right:12px;}
    #hpShareYourProjects {width:245px;float:left;padding-right:3px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't see the image or the HTML, so it's hard to be specific.

Try adding this:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

If that fixes it, you have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584004/remove-extra-space-at-bottom-of-html-list-item/6584455#6584455).

If that works, you can apply `vertical-align: top` to only the `img` elements that need it instead of all of them (though it's unlikely to matter).

Comment: display: block is the other 'fix' for this behaviour; of course, these properties have other side-effects, so it's likely that one may be more appropriate than the other