# UL in DIV wont update height

Tags: html, css

When you hover over the navigation bar, the button should change color.

However, in my case, the button changes color, but it does not do such all the way to the bottom of the navigation bar (you can still see some gray under the black).

How do I make it so that it does go all the way to the bottom?

Also, for some reason, it will go all the way down in google chrome, but not in other browsers.

index.html

```
<div id ="nav">
<ul id = "navbar" class = "navigationbar">
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown3</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class = "dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Not Dropdown</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and style.css

```
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0 padding:0;}
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }

#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:lightslategray;
min-width: 100%;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
}

#nav li {
height:100%;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 300%;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}

#nav{
width: 100%;
display:table;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: lightslategray;
}

.dropdown a{
height: 65%;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
}

.dropbtn{
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;

}

.dropdown a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color:black;
color: white;
}

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
z-index: 20;
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1; color: black;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: don't understand the problem.  https://jsfiddle.net/un6vcgqz/

Comment: What doesn't it work? Safari seams also ok.

Comment: For me, if you hover over the options (especially noticeable with the non-dropdown), the black color won't fully go down to the bottom of the nav bar. (Thanks for making a jsfiddle btw!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could replicate the error on Edge and Firefox. Make one of the following changes to ul.navbar. (Tested only in firefox).

1. `display: inline-block` to `display: block`
2. Add `vertical-align: top` or `bottom`
3. Remove `overflow: hidden`

1 and 2 are from here: [Remove Extra Space at Bottom of HTML List Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584004/remove-extra-space-at-bottom-of-html-list-item), I'm not sure why 3 works.

Comment: Thanks! Worked very well! Must ask though, does any one know why it worked on chrome, but not on Firefox or other browsers?

Comment: Different browsers have different default styles. I don't know the specific for browsers, but that's why this is a thing: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/